# Django how to allow multiple selection without ctrl click

Tags: django, forms, multi-select, multiplechoicefield

I have a listbox on a Django form

```
forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.widgets.SelectMultiple())
```

How can I enable multiple choice with a simple click to select/unselect , without having to press the ctrl key ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be better to just write this as a list of checkboxes, so with a [**`CheckboxSelectMultiple`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple):

```
my_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

You can wrap it into a scrollable, but by working with checkboxes, it is clear what is selected and what not, and one can easily toggle a single element.

Comment: It may be a good alternative thanks. but if  possible, I would really rather stick with the Listbox style

Comment: @Nico44044: well Django does not control that, that is the browser that determines how a `<select>` behaves. You can try to alter it with some JavaScript, but the main problem is, the behavior can even change between browsers, so "fixing" it for one browser can make it worse for another one.

Comment: Ok I got it. I will try to go with your solution and adapt the rest of my code. Thanks

Comment: Just si I know, do you have a hint on how to fix this behavior in JS ?

Comment: @Nico44044: well most javascript libraries will create something themselves with a `<div>` that thus *looks* like a select, but is not, like a select2: https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox